# Check if the given time is between two times (Hour,Minute) format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have next 6 fields in MySQL.

```
TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR (INT)
TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE (INT)
TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR (INT)
TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE (INT)
TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR (INT)
TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE (INT)
```

Hour and minutes are in 24 time format.

I need to check is the right now time between two working times.
for example if TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR is 15 and TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE  is 30 -> 15:30
is it between TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR 10, TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE 15
10:15 and TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR 18, TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE 20 -> 18:20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [maketime()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_maketime) is what you are seeking.

```
SELECT 1
FROM table
WHERE 
  MAKETIME(TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR,TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE,0)
    BETWEEN MAKETIME(TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR,TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE,0)
    AND MAKETIME(TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR,TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE,0);
```

Comment: This is ok. But when i put work time from 23:00 to 5:00 and right now time to 3:00 it is not showing result can i solve this somehow?

Comment: Add in the date. In your application, you can specify the date and time of the work as individual fields, but then before inserting it into the database do some manipulations of those values to create a datestring (2013-11-27 23:00:00), and store that in a single column as a timestamp. That way, you don't even need MAKETIME(), and can simply do NOW() BETWEEN TIME_WORKING_FROM AND TIME_WORKING_TO

Comment: You can solve this by observing that *if the start time is greater than the stop time, the test results are reversed*. So, since 3 is **not** between 5 and 23, **and** 23 is more than 5, then 03:00 **is** between 23:00 and 05:00; and **is not** between 05:00 and 23:00. See my answer for the test.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy solution: Convert hour&time to float then compare:

```
    TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE / 100 -----> 10.15
    TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE / 100; ------> 18.20
    TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR + TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE / 100; ------> 15.30
```

SQL WHERE:

```
    WHERE ( (TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE / 100) <= (TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR +   TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE / 100) )
    AND ( (TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE / 100) >= (TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR +     TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE / 100) )
```

Comment: Solution of @Ian Schoonover is good but it only work for MySQL. My solution can work with ALL SQL databases.

Comment: yes but still i have a problem when working time is 23:00 -> 5:00

Comment: @Vuk Vasić: See my new another answer and let me know your result.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for both 5:00 -> 23:00 and 23:00 -> 5:00 ( NEXT day)

```
    WHERE
    (
            -- CASE: 5:00 -> 23:00
            ( 
                    TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE / 100.00 < TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE / 100.00
            )
            AND
            (
                    (
                            TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE / 100.00 <= TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR + TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE / 100.00
                    )
                    AND 
                    (
                            TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE / 100.00 >= TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR + TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE / 100.00
                    )
            )
    )
    OR
    (
            -- CASE: 23:00 -> 5:00 of Next day
            ( 
                    TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE / 100.00 >= TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE / 100.00
            )
            AND
            (
                (
                    TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR + TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE / 100.00 >= TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE / 100.00
                )
                OR
                (
                    TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR + TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE / 100.00 <= TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR + TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE / 100.00
                )
            )
    )
```

Comment: @Lserni: I have 2 statements. The first one is for FROM < TO and second one is for FROM > TO (of NEXT day). I believe it works.

Comment: Yes, now it does. I've prepared a SQLfiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7768/1

Comment: @lserni: Thanks for your test. Please check My answer is correct.

Comment: I did; it is (sorry. Forgot to upvote). There are three "inside" rows in my test data, and your answer now fetches all three, and none of the others (before, I believe you had an OR instead of an AND in your code).

Answer (score 1):

You can use XOR (or the IF function), in order to cope with midnight rolling (i.e., FROM is 22:00, TO is 06:00, and the question is "is 23:30 inside or outside this period?", which mathematically is outside, but clock-wise is inside).

```
SELECT 
    ( TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR*60+TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE < 
    TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR*60+TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE )
    XOR NOT
    (
    TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR*60+TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE BETWEEN
        TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR*60+TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE
        AND
        TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR*60+TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE
    )
```

## Test

```
CREATE TABLE test ( TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR integer, TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE integer, 
TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR integer, TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE integer,
TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR integer, TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE integer );

INSERT INTO test VALUES 
    ( 7, 30, 8, 00, 17, 00 ), 
    ( 12, 30, 8, 00, 17, 00 ),
    ( 4, 30, 22, 00, 06, 00 ),
    ( 0, 0, 22, 00, 06, 00 ),
    ( 22, 0, 6, 0, 6, 5 );

SELECT  TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR AS FROM_H,
    TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE AS FROM_M,
    TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR AS TO_H,
    TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE AS TO_M,
    TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR AS NOW_H,
    TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE AS NOW_M,
    ( TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR*60+TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE < 
    TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR*60+TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE )
    XOR NOT
    (
    TIME_RIGHT_NOW_HOUR*60+TIME_RIGHT_NOW_MINUTE BETWEEN
        TIME_WORKING_FROM_HOUR*60+TIME_WORKING_FROM_MINUTE
        AND
        TIME_WORKING_TO_HOUR*60+TIME_WORKING_TO_MINUTE
    ) AS in_orario FROM test;
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+------+------+-------+-------+-----------+
| FROM_H | FROM_M | TO_H | TO_M | NOW_H | NOW_M | in_orario |
+--------+--------+------+------+-------+-------+-----------+
|      8 |      0 |   17 |    0 |     7 |    30 |         0 |
|      8 |      0 |   17 |    0 |    12 |    30 |         1 |
|     22 |      0 |    6 |    0 |     4 |    30 |         1 |
|     22 |      0 |    6 |    0 |     0 |     0 |         1 |
|      6 |      0 |    6 |    5 |    22 |     0 |         0 |
+--------+--------+------+------+-------+-------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7768/4), the condition has been moved into the `WHERE`.