# I have a mysql query issue

Tags: mysql

My MySQL Query is OK with 22:29:50 But after 22:30:00 and end_time is next day 07:29:59 The Query is not working.

MY TABLE is shift

```
shift_name |start_time | end_time
shift1     | 07:30:00  |15:30:00
shift2     | 15:30:00  | 22:30:00
shift3     | 22:30:00  | 07:30:00
```

I write the following query

```
select shift_name from shift 
where time('22:30:00') BETWEEN start_time and end_time;
```

Comment: *"and end_time is next day `07:29:59`"* -- the *next day* part is not expressed anywhere in the data.

Comment: Without date components it is a bit hard to judge what is an actual shift.  Is there a reason why you have no dates here?

Comment: `shift3` crosses midnight, so you need to work with full `datetime` values and not only **hh:mm:ss**.

Comment: The overnight is your probleme at the moment you literally check for shift 3: e.g. Is 23 between 22 - 7. Which doesnt makes any sense. Here is your problem also asked and some answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251573/check-if-the-given-time-is-between-two-times-hour-minute-format

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please give right answer for. Above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE shift 
>     (`shift_name` varchar(6), `start_time` time, `end_time` time);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO shift 
>     (`shift_name`, `start_time`, `end_time`)
> VALUES
>     ('shift1', '07:30:00', '15:30:00'),
>     ('shift2', '15:30:00', '22:30:00'),
>     ('shift3', '22:30:00', '07:30:00');
> ```

> ```
> select 
>      *
> from (
>      select cast('05:22' as time) t
>     ) d
> cross join shift
> where (t >= start_time and t < end_time) 
> or  (t >= cast('00:00' as time) and t < end_time and start_time > end_time ) 
> or  (t >= start_time and start_time > end_time )
> ```
>
> ```
> t        | shift_name | start_time | end_time
> :------- | :--------- | :--------- | :-------
> 05:22:00 | shift3     | 22:30:00   | 07:30:00
> ```

> ```
> select 
>      *
> from (
>      select cast('23:52' as time) t
>     ) d
> cross join shift
> where (t >= start_time and t < end_time) 
> or  (t >= cast('00:00' as time) and t < end_time and start_time > end_time ) 
> or  (t >= start_time and start_time > end_time )
> ```
>
> ```
> t        | shift_name | start_time | end_time
> :------- | :--------- | :--------- | :-------
> 23:52:00 | shift3     | 22:30:00   | 07:30:00
> ```

> ```
> select 
>      *
> from (
>      select cast('10:52' as time) t
>     ) d
> cross join shift
> where (t >= start_time and t < end_time) 
> or  (t >= cast('00:00' as time) and t < end_time and start_time > end_time ) 
> or  (t >= start_time and start_time > end_time )
> ```
>
> ```
> t        | shift_name | start_time | end_time
> :------- | :--------- | :--------- | :-------
> 10:52:00 | shift1     | 07:30:00   | 15:30:00
> ```

> ```
> select 
>      *
> from (
>      select cast('19:52' as time) t
>     ) d
> cross join shift
> where (t >= start_time and t < end_time) 
> or  (t >= cast('00:00' as time) and t < end_time and start_time > end_time ) 
> or  (t >= start_time and start_time > end_time )
> ```
>
> ```
> t        | shift_name | start_time | end_time
> :------- | :--------- | :--------- | :-------
> 19:52:00 | shift2     | 15:30:00   | 22:30:00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=b75d346d239ca99316c0ae3d052e611a)*

Comment: yes, you have to add another day to time if it earlier than 07:30. e.g. this will actually work: `select *
from shift_v
where concat(curdate(),' ','24:59:59') between start_datetime and end_datetime
;`  the point is you cannot do this without date as well as time

Comment: Thanks For valuable answer.